# In R, remove substring pattern from string with gsub

Tags: r, string, gsub

We have a string column in our database with values for sports teams. The names of these teams are occasionally prefixed with the team's ranking, like such: `(13) Miami (FL)`. Here the 13 is Miami's rank, and the (FL) means this is Miami Florida, not Miami of Ohio (`Miami (OH)`):

We need to clean up this string, removing `(13)`  and keeping only `Miami (FL)`. So far we've used `gsub` and tried the following:

```
> gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", "", "(13) Miami (FL)")
[1] " Miami"
```

This is incorrectly removing the (FL) suffix, and it's also not handling the white space correctly in front.

### Edit

Here's a few additional school names, to show a bit the data we're working with. Note that not every school has the (##) prefix.:

```
c("North Texas", "Southern Methodist", "Texas-El Paso", 
  "Brigham Young", "Winner", "(12) Miami (FL)", "Appalachian State", 
  "Arkansas State", "Army", "(1) Clemson", 
  "(14) Georgia Southern")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to remove a number in brackets followed by whitespace.

```
sub("\\(\\d+\\)\\s", "", "(13) Miami (FL)")
#[1] "Miami (FL)"
```

The regex could be made stricter based on the pattern in data.

Answer (score 1):

We can match the opening `(` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), then the closing `)`) and one or more spaces (`\\s+`), replace with blanks (`""`)

```
sub("\\(\\d+\\)\\s+", "",  "(13) Miami (FL)")
#[1] "Miami (FL)"
```

Using the OP' updated example

```
sub("\\(\\d+\\)\\s+", "",  v1)
#[1] "North Texas"        "Southern Methodist" "Texas-El Paso"      "Brigham Young"      "Winner"             "Miami (FL)"        
#[7] "Appalachian State"  "Arkansas State"     "Army"               "Clemson"            "Georgia Southern"
```

---

Or another option with `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove("(13) Miami (FL)", "\\(\\d+\\)\\s+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, based on `stringr`, is this:

```
str_extract(v1, "[A-Z].*")
 [1] "North Texas"        "Southern Methodist" "Texas-El Paso"      "Brigham Young"      "Winner"            
 [6] "Miami (FL)"         "Appalachian State"  "Arkansas State"     "Army"               "Clemson"           
[11] "Georgia Southern"
```

This extracts everything starting from the first upper case letter (thereby ignoring the unwanted rankings).